# chef versioning - is there an order of precedence?

Tags: chef-infra

As i understand it, you can set the version for a cookbook in its `metadata.rb` file.

You can subsequently reference that version in three places. Other cookbook metadata, environments or run_lists.

What happens if you specify a version constraint for the same cookbook in more than one of those locations with different version numbers. Which version is enforced?

The reason for asking is if a Role isn't versioned like a cookbook... and maybe the production environment is configured to lock versions to known good cookbooks but an admin comes along and updates a recipe in the Roles run_list like apache@1.2.2 so it's different to that of the environments constraints.. which wins.

Hope that makes sense.

fLo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dependency solver in Chef will (unfortunately silently) use the
best version of a dependent cookbook it can to solve the graph. That
means if you have:

- cookbook runit exists on the Chef server at version 0.13.2 and 1.2.0
- cookbook myface depends on runit with no version constraint operator
- cookbook yourface depends on runit with ~> 0.13.0

When the node's expanded run list contains `recipe[myface]` and
`recipe[yourface]`, it will use runit version 0.13.2.

If Chef cannot solve the graph, it will return an HTTP 412,
precondition failed. For example if you lock the version of runit in
the environment to = 1.2.0, and both `recipe[myface]` and
`recipe[yourface]` are in the run list, it will be unable to solve the
graph because yourface wants v0.13.2.

Another scenario:

- cookbook couchdb exists with versions 1.1.0 and 1.0.0
- cookbook couchdb version 1.1.0 depends on runit ~> 1.1
- cookbook couchdb version 2.0.0 depends on runit >= 1.0.0 (the major
  version bump was fixing a dependency so the earlier version could
  be used)
- cookbook myface depends on couchdb >= 1.1.0 (and transitively runit
  1.2.0)
- cookbook yourface depends on couchdb ~> 2.0.0 (and transitively runit
  1.0.0)

When the node's run list again contains both `recipe[myface]` and
`recipe[yourface]`, then you'll probably end up with:

- couchdb 2.0.0 (due to yourface pessimistic constraint, and this
  satisfies myface's 1.1.0 requirement)
- runit 1.1 (due to couchdb 2.0.0's requirement)

This may or may not be what you actually want, however, because
perhaps the behavior in the different couchdb cookbooks is different
for the application in some way unrelated to its use of runit. It's
probably fine though.

It's generally fine to set dependencies in your cookbooks' metadata on community cookbooks depending on your needs. For some cookbooks, liberal constraints (or none at all) are fine. For other cookbooks, pessimistic constrinats (with the ~> operator) are probably good. This is on a case-by-case basis, so I don't have general advice. Keep an eye on the changelogs or commit logs of the cookbooks you're interested in and see if the author has a habit of breaking things between minor releases, for example.

It is recommended for environments, especially production/stable type environments, to pin cookbook versions with the `=` operator. This is what we (Chef, the company) do with the cookbooks that run Hosted Chef (the Chef Server SaaS).

Comment: is there a way to make it more verbose while resolving the dependency graph?

Comment: unfortunately no, not in the current release (11.10.4) nor earlier. Debug output (-l debug) doesn't show these things. There may be server-side logs, but as the "Chef Server" I operate is "Hosted Enteprise Chef," the logs are a bit .. verbose (N customers hitting the API constantly and all).

Answer (score 1):

Remember there are the cookbook entries that appear on the run-list *and* additional cookbooks that are listed as dependencies in the various metadata files. At run-time chef must construct a tree of cookbook versions to determine the actual version of each cookbook that will be used.

For example cookbook B could depend on >v3.0 of cookbook X, whereas cookbook B could depend on >version 1.0. So it's not really a matter of which cookbook "wins", it's more about whether chef satisfy the constraints on versions that it discovers and meet those constraints from the available cookbook versions loaded.

When it comes to constraints you are best advised to place these in two only two places:

- Cookbook dependencies in the environment file.
- Runlist of the Environment

Why?

1. Less confusing
2. Constraints on the environment is supported by knife when uploading cookbooks
3. As you point out roles are not versioned, and setting versions on the role run-list would apply to all chef server environments...
4. Using the cookbook to control the run-list is a new pattern and the metadata version and dependencies automatically control the versions to be chosen.

Comment: So if in the prod environment, i had 'cookbook_versions({ "couchdb"=>"= 11.0.0" }' and then in a cookbook metadata i have 'depends "couchdb", "= 12.0.0"' which a node in the prod environment has this cookbook in its runlist.. then this would fail because the environments constraint limits the nodes version scope of this cookbook to just 11.0.0 ?

Comment: @FloWoo It's worth testing. If the dependency is a hard one on "12.0.0" and that version is loaded, I'd imagine that is what will be selected. I've only seen Chef throw errors when two cookbooks have hard "=" metadata *dependencies* on the same 3rd party cookbook.