# chef - precedence of attributes set on node level

Tags: chef-infra, knife

Maybe I missed something in the doc's, but after reading the order that attributes are used when defined in multiple places I don't understand where attributes set at the **node level** come into the equation

In the 1 to 15 levels of where attributes can be set and overridden, it mentions recipe, environment, role, attribute file but it never seems to mention what happens to attributes defined on a node, say by `knife node edit ...`

It looks like you can only define attributes of *normal* type on a node? Normal attributes are only mentioned for priority levels 7 and 8 in the list... attribute files and recipes respectively.

So if I set an attribute on the node that was also defined on the environment and role levels who wins?

Comment: Answer my own question here in case someone else stumbles across this question.

Chef doc's say there are 15 precedence levels..wrong. There are 16.

If you edit a nodes JSON, you can set normal attributes there. These values supersedes the same key/value pair set with force_default in a recipe but not normal values set in cookbook attribute file. 

Also, the Chef documentation implies that you can set node JSON attributes at various types..you can't. It accepts normal type only. If you try to use another type it will be silently removed from the config on saving when using 'knife edit node..'

Comment: This question is not a duplicate of [chef versioning - is there an order of precedence](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20717804/chef-versioning-is-there-an-order-of-precedence) - that question pertains to cookbook versions, and this question pertains to node attribute precedence.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[The Chef Documentation](http://docs.opscode.com/chef_overview_attributes.html) has a [table showing the node attribute precedence](http://docs.opscode.com/_images/overview_chef_attributes_table.png). If you edit a node object on the Chef server, or provide node attributes with a JSON file (`-j` option to chef-solo or chef-client), these are all the "node" level. This is the same level as setting attributes from a recipe. To whit, you can easily set any level of node attribute in a recipe w/ the attribute methods (node.normal, etc) except automatic. On the node object itself (in the Chef Server), you can set default, normal, and override, but not force_default or force_override, nor automatic.

The general guideline we tell people is to always use default attributes:

1. `default['thing'] = 'thang'` - in a cookbook's attributes file.
2. `node.default['thing'] = 'thang'` - in a recipe.
3. `"default": { "thing": "thang" }` - in the node object's JSON
4. `default_attributes("thing" => "thang")` - in a role ([ruby DSL syntax shown](http://docs.opscode.com/essentials_roles.html#ruby-dsl)).
5. Generally avoid `environment` set attributes...

And when the need arises for you to set attributes elsewhere at other priorities, you will just know. :)

It may seem arbitrarily over-engineered; originally there were only the node object/recipe and attributes files, and they were just Ruby hashes. Then we added roles, and environments. At some point in there too came the need to set "default" values that could be overridden easily, arbitrarily for various organizational reasons, and now we have the matrix you see today. We're pretty happy with things now, and think it provides the most flexibility for the extremely wide variety of Chef use cases.

**Note**

This question is not a duplicate of [chef versioning - is there an order of precedence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20717804/chef-versioning-is-there-an-order-of-precedence) - that question pertains to cookbook versions, and this question pertains to node attribute precedence.

Also note that because recipes are Ruby, and executed by the client you can write libraries to manipulate attributes in interesting ways. An example is [Chef's whitelist-node-attrs cookbook](http://community.opscode.com/cookbooks/whitelist-node-attrs).

Comment: Hi... thanks for the info but what you are telling me isn't what i see when testing. When i try 'knife edit node...' and try to set any attribute key/value pair of any type other than normal i just get the output 'Node not updated, skipping node save' after saving the changes in vim. I sometimes get Yajl::ParseError as well when i try to define a default or override pair. This is with knife 11.8.2.


Can you give a gist or example of a node json where key/value attributes are set at normal, default, override etc.. as the "attribute precedence" document page suggests is possible?

Thanks.

Comment: ok, never mind... i found the answer and it's annoying.

---- The edit command does not, by default, edit automatic, default, or override attributes, in order to do this you must pass the -a or --all flag to the edit command, which will allow you to edit all of the attributes that are currently set on the node. The documentation indicates that the --all only controls what is shown.. not that it prevents you from adding/editing the node JSON unless used.

Comment: Note that you cannot edit automatic attributes on the node object. Those are generated by ohai's plugins (built in or your own) when chef-client runs.

Comment: ok, thanks.. final question regarding this topic.. If the only way to see AND edit all node attributes types is to pass the --all parameter which also lists the nodes automatic info from ohai. How do you backup node JSON from the server, locally to be stored in SCM, without downloading the JSON with automatic info. If its dynamic it isn't really needed to be stored/backed-up? Thanks.

Comment: Use the knife download sub-command (available in Chef 11, or via the knife-essentials gem) to download the JSON object. The automatic attributes will be overridden by the node next time it runs chef after restoring.

Comment: @jtimberman: Where in the attribute precedence list are values that are already in the node object? 6.5? After force_default but before normal?